# Universal app background SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on universal game (iPhone and iPad) with SpriteKit and I have issue with background size. 
I created image size 2048x1536 and more image for iPhone devices in size 1136x852 and still the background is cropped on iPhone.
How can I fix it?

```
let screenHeight = screenSize.size.height

    //Backgorund

    var dayBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"BackgroundDay")
    dayBackground.zPosition = -1
    dayBackground.position = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y:size.height/2)
    dayBackground.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    dayBackground.size = self.frame.size
```

GameViewController:

```
     if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

iPhone 6 Plus:
[image: The background is cropped]

iPad Pro:
[image: Fit to screen]

iPhone 4s:
[image: Cropped background]

Assets file:
[image: @1x size is 2048x1536 and @3x is 1136x852]

@1x size is 2048x1536 and @3x is 1136x852
The sense scale is `.AspectFill` with `.ResizeAll` the position of SKSprtieNode it not like what I want.
Thanks!

I tried to split the image to parts but still is cropped
I think is happen because the iPhone 6 plus screen size is 736x414 and the scene size is 1024x768, and if I change the scene to the current device I need to position the sprites for each screen
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: I see all games use same image for all size how can I do it with scale by screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devices's screen size ratios are different, and one will have to stretch dimensions to fit the screen, and this may look weird. But you can use .Fill if you are sure you like this option. The smoothest alternative is to remain using .AspectFill and create an image for each screen dimension. Be creative! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! SpriteKit is hard :(

Comment: No problem! I started learning swift with SpriteKit.. The past few weeks I've been trying to learn UIKit, now that is hard.

Comment: But how can I position SKSpriteNode in same position on all device?

Comment: If your game is bound by the device's screen, than you can use .Fill, as long as you remember to set .xScale and .yScale individually... And I can send you a link to a similar question when I get to my computer

Comment: Wow! You are an amazing artist. Try breaking the image into 4 parts: the light blue background, the ground, the title, and the clouds. The best thing to do is position them all separately so that they will fit on any iPad dimension. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! but still the background is cropped. I think is happen because the iPhone 6 plus screen size is 736x414 and the scene size is 1024x768, and if I change the scene to the current device I need to position the sprites for each screen

Comment: Try making the positions relative, eg percentages of the screen's bounds. If you look at my profile, I have answered a few questions regarding how to do this